# Upload Event photo using Facebook-C#-SDK

Tags: asp.net-mvc, facebook-c#-sdk

I'm using the facebook-c#-sdk to create events on facebook, and that part it's working fine, but now i don't know how to use the sdk to upload the photo for my event.

what sould i do?

i'm using a asp.net mvc3 app

Answer (score 0):

I've done what you intend to do by following [this tutorial](http://blog.prabir.me/post/Facebook-CSharp-SDK-Upload-Progress.aspx). For posting to events, just make a minor change at the PostAsync method, instead of sending the data to "/me/photos/", change the "me" (which refers to your account's photo albums) to your event's ID.

Figured this out by reading the [Facebook Graph API reference](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/event/#photos), which is super easy, and I suggest you do the same!

Cheers!